# Как парсить картинки в гугле для телеграм бота?

Tags: python, selenium, telegram

Как сделать парсер картинок в гугле при помощи selenium для телеграм бота? Пробовал такой вариант, но не работает.

```
import telebot
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\FILES\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\geckodriver.exe')
Token = '...'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(Token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
def seeaarch(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что именно?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, searchForPhoto)
def searchForPhoto(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Так где оно тут у нас...')
    photo_href = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + message.text + "&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiBz5Svn5XxAhXkkcMKHa2uD5sQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=" + message.text + "&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAUPUMWPUMYNgPaABwAHgAgAFPiAFPkgEBMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=MU_GYMHyHuSjjgat3b7YCQ&bih=937&biw=1920"
    driver.get(photo_href)
    photos = driver.find_element_by_class_name("rg_i Q4LuWd")
    for v in range(len(photos)):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, photos[v].get_attribute('img'))

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Требуется именно selenium? https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview ?

Comment: Да, именно selenium